# Access Path.GetTempPath(); fails

Tags: c#, .net, filesystems

I am facing a special problem concerning the environment variable TMP on my system, I think.

This variable is defined like this:

```
TMP=c:\profiles\myUser\LOKALE~1\temp
```

Writing to this location via the .net application is not possible whereas through the windows explorer I can easily create files.

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Regards,
MacX

Comment: Are you getting an exception? If yes what? Which user you are running your application under? Does it have permissions to write to `c:\profiles\myUser\LOKALE~1\temp`?

Comment: I don't understand, are you trying to create a temporary file? if so you can use Path.GetTempPath or GetTempFile or similar, without caring on where the file is really saved.

Comment: I am trying to save a temporary file for displaying it to the user. But I am not able to store it with the Application. Instead within the explorer I am able to write to the directory. Maybe this problem relies to the character '~' within the environment variable? the variable TMP is the same as TMPDIR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is not the variable itself, but the way I access the files to open it.
I try to open the files via a console-parameter, where blanks a treated as seperators, if the paths are not quotet.

```
excel.exe c:\path tofile\excelfile.xls
```

should be quoted and look like this

```
excel.exe "c:\path tofile\excelfile.xls"
```

That's it.

Because I didn't write the app myself, I had to look this part up in the source code. But thanks a lot, for the hints.

MacX

Answer (score 4):

Actually according to the MSDN:

Referring to Path.GetTempPath
This method checks for the existence of environment variables in the following order and uses the first path found:

- The path specified by the TMP
  environment variable.
- The path specified by the TEMP
  environment variable.
- The path specified by the USERPROFILE
  environment variable.
- The Windows directory.

It doesn't specify if it checks if the running process has write access so depending on the process rights it may not be able to write.